# How to connect a database to website using LINQ and dbml file

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, linq-to-sql

I am new to SQL server and trying to make a very simple website which will record  usernames and passwords from clients into a database. I have created a database project with a table of users: *user name* and *password*. I built a website with a page containing `user name` text field, `password` text field and a `login` button. All I want is to record the usernames and passwords the users are entering (as simple as that). I want to do it via sql connection using LINQ-to-SQL. I know that I have to create SQLConnection class, create a dbml file and attach my database to it. I am having trouble creating a dbml file of my database and attaching my database to it in Visual Studio 2013. Can anyone please give direction to do so?

So far I have this class for the login page:

```
public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string connStr = "data source=.; database = AuroraDB; integrated security=SSPI";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TODO"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {    

        string insertQuery = "insert into Users (Username, Password,) values(@uname , @password)";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", UserNameTextBox.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", PasswordTextBox.Text);
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Write("Loggin was successful!");

        }
        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Response.Write("Error occurred: " + exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forget todo this `ConnectionStrings["TODO"]` as your not using the `connStr` variable you declared

Comment: On a side note, storing passwords as clear text is a very bad and unethical thing to do, users might be reusing their passwords on other sites etc....

Comment: I still don't figured out how exactly to use assemble this string and how to use it with LINQ so take these lines as limited liability.

Comment: For now I just want to achieve some basic functionality so the way I store the password will be changed...

Comment: Try using the following overload `new SqlConnection(connStr);`